# Use of information theory in applied data science

Tags: information-theory

Today I ran across the book ["Information theory: A tutorial introduction"](http://jim-stone.staff.shef.ac.uk/BookInfoTheory/InfoTheoryBookMain.html) by James Stone and thought for a moment or two about the **extent of use** of information theory in **applied** *data science* (if you're not comfortable with this still somewhat fuzzy term, think *data analysis*, which IMHO data science is a glorified version of). I'm well aware of the significant use of *information theory*-based *approaches*, *methods* and *measures*, especially *entropy*, **under the hood** of various statistical techniques and data analysis methods.

However, I'm curious about the **extent/level** of knowledge that is needed for an *applied social scientist* to successfully **select** and **apply** those concepts, measures and tools without diving too deep into mathematical origins of the theory. I look forward to your answers, which might address my concern within the context of the above-mentioned book (or other similar books - feel free to recommend) or in general.

I would also appreciate some recommendations for print or online sources that discuss **information theory** and its concepts, approaches, methods and measures in the **context** of (in **comparison** with) other (more) **traditional statistical approaches** (*frequentist* and *Bayesian*).

Comment: Perhaps one of the most known and "applied" case of use of entropy takes place when building up a tree. One of the possibilities when algorithm splits is to take the information gain metric, which is the difference between entropy between the top level and the down level. You have more information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_in_decision_trees

Comment: @D.Castro: Thank you for your comment - I'm aware of that case (and even posted an answer on this exact topic either here on Cross Validated, or on Data Science SE site). I'm hoping for a more comprehensive coverage/discussion of the subject matter.

Comment: For me, and in large part, it's a matter of the discipline or field in which one is trained as well as the geographic continent. In my view, physicists, mathematicians and practitioners of pure machine learning are much more likely to receive in-depth exposure to information theory than are, say, statisticians, economists or quantitative financial analysts. In addition, I would double down on this for people trained in Europe, i.e., Europeans are much more likely to be familiar with IT. However, the advent of models for statistical learning is changing that for data scientists in the States.

Comment: @DJohnson Minutest of minute points but in Britain and perhaps elsewhere  IT == information technology. Otherwise your impressions resemble mine.

Comment: @NickCox  Thanks, your point holds for the States as well. It was a longish comment and, space permitting, I would have spelled the words out or, better yet, have introduced the meaning of the acronym at an earlier point.

Comment: @DJohnson But information theory and information technology are quite different! Are you taking them to be synonyms?

Comment: @NickCox  Of course not. I was merely trying to clarify that, due to the length of the full comment, I chose to compress *Information Theory* down to *IT*, hoping that readers would understand.

Comment: OK; that's understood then.

Comment: @NickCox Hope you're doing well and have enjoyed great holidays. It seems a bit late in the day to be adding to this thread but Luciano Floridi's work on ethics and information seems quite relevant. In particular, watch these two Youtube posted lectures ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEvyHf7xJa0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl9ljZMO-Cs

Comment: @DJohnson 3 hours of lectures! Thanks for the tip. Do they say anything about information theory in the Shannon-Wiener sense?

Comment: @nickcox  Quite a bit actually. One of the shifts or fault lines Floridi identifies is the one between syntax and semantics, mechanics and meaning. This is Shannon-Weaver in its essence.

Comment: @NickCox  It may simplify things if you focus on the first talk (above).

Answer (score 4):

So the first part of question: *Do data scientists need to know information theory*? I thought the answer is no until very recently. The reason I changed my mind is one crucial component: noise.

Many machine learning models (both stochastic or not) use noise as part of their encoding and transformation process and in many of these models, you need to infer the probability which the noise affected after decoding the transformed output of the model. I think that this is a core part of information theory. Not only that, in deep learning, KL divergence is a very important measure used that also comes from Information Theory.

Second part of the question: I think the best source is David MacKay's [Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521642981). He starts with Information Theory and takes those ideas into both inference and even neural networks. The Pdf is free on [Dave's website](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.html) and the [lectures are online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCiZc0n6COY&list=PLruBu5BI5n4aFpG32iMbdWoRVAA-Vcso6) which are great

Comment: It's an excellent book. Anyone interested should also glance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._C._MacKay

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1 and potential accept, if no more comprehensive answers will pop up soon enough). Special appreciation for the references. I'm surprised you ran across this almost forgotten, but important, question of mine. :-)

Comment: Yeah it's interesting. You should never give up on a question. Came to me after I attended NIPS2016 and I saw all those talks on KL divergence and noise impact to encoders.